# php - get image urls from wordpress posts

Tags: php, image, wordpress, url

I have website based on wordpress system and I need to get images urls from every post. I have this code and it's working, but there is problem, because all of posts have same pictures + at the end, there are new ones. Here is example:

> **post1** - image1.png,image2.png,image3.png
>
> **post2** - image1.png,image2.png,image3.png,new1.png,new2.png
>
> **post3** - image1.png,image2.png,image3.png,new1.png,new2.png,third.png
>
> etc...

And here is my php code

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$old_content, $imgTags); 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgTags[0]); $i++) {

  // get the source string
  preg_match('/src="([^"]+)/i',$imgTags[0][$i], $imgage);

  // remove opening 'src=' tag, can`t get the regex right
  $origImageSrc[] = str_ireplace( 'src="', '',  $imgage[0]);
}
```

Any ideas, why it's doing? :-)

Comment: you can get teh image of post or page feature imag by function   <?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you out, here's a function that you can throw into your functions.php file in your Wordpress theme.

```
/*
 * Retreive url's for image attachments from a post
 */

function getPostImages($size = 'full'){
    global $post;
    $urls = array();

    $images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
        'post_status' => 'inheret',
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ));

    if(isset($images)){
        foreach($images as $image){
            $imgThumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size, false);
            $urls[] = $imgThumb[0];
        }  

        return $urls;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

That will return an array with each image url that is attached to the post/page.  To loop thru and show all of the images in an `<ul>` you could do something like this.

```
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <ul id="post_images">
        <?php $postImages = getPostImages($size = 'full'); ?>
        <?php foreach($postImages as $image): ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```